# No tabbar when switching fragments

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar

I have 1 Activity with 2 fragments in it, say FragmentA and FragmentB.
The activity layout only has an empty FrameLayout to embed the fragments.
Fragment A has no toolbar and is a "first run" fragment, that is only shown the first time that the app runs, 
Fragment B has a toolbar, a tabbar and a viewpager.

When the activity starts for the first time, FragmentA is shown correctly.
When FragmentA ends, the Activity switches to FragmentB.
Here something weird happens with the toolbar: only the title of the app is shown, no tabs, no toolbar, although there is whitespace where it should be. In fact, when you look at the bounds via the developer options, it looks as if 2 tabs are drawn (there should be 4 in our app).

This is a screenshot without the developer option boundaries
[image]

When you rotate the screen or exit the app and open it for a second time (the activity directly displays FragmentB on recreate), everything is back to normal: FragmentB is shown with the correct tabs and toolbar.

What did I do wrong? Or is this a bug in the support libraries?

Fragment B layout is shown here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The code for Fragment B is

```
public class FragmentB extends BaseFragment
{

    @Bind(R.id.tabs)
    TabLayout tabLayout;

    @Bind(R.id.viewpager)
    ViewPager viewPager;

    @Bind(R.id.toolbar)
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);

        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        BaseActivity activity = (BaseActivity) getActivity();
        activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        this.viewPager.setAdapter(new SomePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), getActivity()));

        this.tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Code for SomePagerAdapter

```
public class SomePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    private String[] tabNames;

    public SomePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context)
    {
        super(fm);
        tabNames = new String[]{
            context.getString(R.string.tab_title_1),
            context.getString(R.string.tab_title_2),
            context.getString(R.string.tab_title_3),
            context.getString(R.string.tab_title_4)
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        try
        {
            switch (position)
            {
                case 0:
                    return Tab1Fragment.class.newInstance();
                default:
                    return PlaceholderFragment.class.newInstance();
            }
        }
        catch (InstantiationException e)
        {
            Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e)
        {
            Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return tabNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {$
        return tabNames[position];
    }
}
```

I use the following versions of the support libraries:

```
'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
```

Comment: Since you say layout bounds is showing only two tabs, perhaps the problem is with the pager adapter? Can you post the code?

Comment: @Hindol I added the pager adapter ;) Nothing special there I think

Comment: `Tab1Fragment` and `FragmentA` are same thing?

Comment: No Tab1Fragment is the fragment of the first viewpager tab, this viewpager is embedded in FragmentB in the Activity. FragmentA is the first run fragment shown in the activity. (So both FragmentA and FragmentB are embedded in the Activity, the viewpager and its page fragments are embedded in FragmentB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Google fixed this issue in v23 of the support design library